# Configure Behat to set env variable to test

Tags: php, bash

I've created a simple php application from scratch. In my composer.json I've this dependencies. They all works fine, but I also need to create a "test" environment (with different configurations).

In symfony this is done automatically. I suppose I need to `export` some variable in bash. Some env variable.

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5",
        "behat/behat": "^3.2",
        "behat/mink-extension": "@dev",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@dev"
    }
}
```

I've tryed with bash script like this:

```
# bash
export MY_VAR=test
```

but when I try to read the variable with

```
// php
var_dump(getenv('MY_VAR'))
```

var_dump always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you mentioned composer - it has nothing to do with environment configuration.

`getenv` works perfectly fine for php_cli:

```
$ MY_VAR=test php -r "var_dump(getenv('MY_VAR'));"
```

outputs `string(4) "test"`.

For mod_php you should set environment variable in relevant VirtualHost definition:

```
SetEnv MY_VAR test
```

and for php_fpm you should do the same in relevant pool.d/ config:

```
env[MY_VAR] = test
```